# Low voltage induction heating working

Tags: power-electronics, induction-heater

I have a question regarding the working of induction heater when powered with low DC voltage source. I have seen some with 12-48V DC in eCommerces like AliExpress.

I have knowledge on how induction heating works but only for 230V AC and high frequency based circuits.

My question is how is power decided on low voltage induction heating? For example a 3kW circuit at 12-48VDC does this mean a workpiece is around 0.048 Ohm which cause a current of 250A to flow or is there any thing that decides power besides workpiece resistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ideal cases we have the following relation between power, current, voltage, and resistance: `Power dissipated (P) = V*I = I^2 * R = V^2/R`

In the above situation `P = 3000 W`, `R = 0.048 ohms` and minimum voltage `Vmin = 12V` and maximum voltage `Vmax = 48V`

Substituting these values, we can compute the minimum and maximum currents possible `Imin = 3000W/48V = 62.5A` and `Imax = 3000W/12V = 250A`

Now that we have `(Vmin,Imin)` and `(Vmax,Imax)` we can now compute the possible loads that the circuit can support using Ohm's law `V=I*R` and this gives `Rmin = 0.048 ohms` and `Rmax = 0.768 ohms`

Comment: Okay so does this mean those bolts being heated red-hot in workshops are around  those resistances?

Answer (score 0):

I'm John DeArmond, the engineer that created that horrible low voltage Royer heater and posted it to the net in about 2001.  In short, over about 50 volts, the gate dropping resistor is so large that the gate is charged slowly and the IGBT remains in its active zone too long and it is destroyed.  I quickly corrected the design but apparently the ChiComs haven't cloned that one.  If you want to read about it and subsequent designs, go here.

https://neon-john.com/Induction/Index.htm

Notice that all offers for boards and other parts has ended.  I'm now retired.

I've been so busy with Fluxeon that I have woefully neglected my website.  When I get time to put the project together suitable for public consumption, I will be posting an open-source, non-Royer, self-tuning, SiC FET based-design with power factor correction and variable power.

Now directly to your question.  The first answer is incorrect or at least woefully incomplete.  The amount of current flowing in the workpiece is dependent on the current flowing in the primary coil AND the turns-ratio, with the work being treated as a shorted one turn coil.

The way I determine the characteristics of a workpiece is to wrap it as tightly as possible with 10 turns of magnetic wire and connect it to a frequency generator.  From the generator to the coil and from the coil back to the low side of the generator through a 22 ohm resistor.  I set the generator to the desired frequency and measure the voltage across the coil and the voltage drop across the resistor for the current and let my digital scope compute the phase angle.  given the voltage, current and phase angle, I can compute back to the workpiece's resistance and inductance and thus the current.

But the current isn't the big thing in ferrous metal below its Curie point (the temperature at which it becomes non-magnetic).  Below the Curie point, the majority of the heating is done by magnetic hysteresis. Only above the Curie point does the resistance and thus the current flowing do the work.